# Not getting Extras from intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have made an application in which i need to pass some values to other activities.For that i am using Intent.putExtras.I debugged my code and in that values are getting stored in extras but when i get the extras at the other activity i am getting null pointer exception.

CustomListAdapter.Java

```
holder.bestCandidate.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HashMap<String, String> row = data.get (i);
                intent = new Intent (context, BestCandidate.class);
                intent.putExtra ("code", row.get ("code"));
                intent.putExtra ("category", row.get ("category"));
                BestCandidateDisplay display = new BestCandidateDisplay ();
                display.execute (row.get ("iJobRequestorId"), "0");
            }
        });
```

ListClass

```
public class BestCandidate extends Activity {
    private ListView lvBestCanditate;
    BestCandidateCustomList customList;
    Context c = this;
    Intent i;
    TextView jobCode, category;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.best_candidate_list);
        initialize ();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        i = new Intent ();
        lvBestCanditate = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView);
        jobCode = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv_job_code);
        category = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tv_category);
        customList = new BestCandidateCustomList (c, SearchJobsCustomList.candidateArray);
        lvBestCanditate.setAdapter (customList);
        i = getIntent ();
        Bundle extras = i.getExtras ();
        jobCode.setText (extras.getString ("code"));
        category.setText (extras.getString ("category"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide code where you call method startActivity()

Comment: i havent called the startActivity.I do not want to call other activity, i just wanna pass the data from one activity to other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, `SharedPreferences` might help you.

Obtain:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Put:

```
String value= "some value";
prefs.edit().putString(pref_key, value).commit();
```

And read where you want:

```
String readValue = prefs.getString(pref_key, "dafault value");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass values from an `Activity` to another you have to use the `putExtra` method on the same `Intent` object as the one you are using when you call `startActivity()`.

If you do not want to launch the other activity just after adding value to the intent you should do like this.

First, define a global `Intent` object:

```
private Intent myIntent;
```

Then, initialize it in the `onCreate` method for example:

```
myIntent = new Intent (context, BestCandidate.class);
```

After that, use it in your code to add values:

```
holder.bestCandidate.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        HashMap<String, String> row = data.get (i);
        myIntent.putExtra ("code", row.get ("code"));
        myIntent.putExtra ("category", row.get ("category"));
        BestCandidateDisplay display = new BestCandidateDisplay ();
        display.execute (row.get ("iJobRequestorId"), "0");
    }
});
```

Finally; use it to launch your new `Activity`;

```
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: but i dont wanna open other activity i nly wanna pass the data

Comment: When will you use the values if you do no launch this new activity?

Answer (score 0):

Oh no. You can't send intent to another activity without run it.
Do something like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_NAME", someValue);
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: the data i m passing is from the customAdapter class so i dnt wanna open the activity i nly wanna pass the data.Is there any another method to pass the data